# Homebrew: Can't start elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm in a big trouble, I can't start Elasticsearch and I need it for run my rails locally, please tell me what's going on. I installed Elasticsearch in the normal fashion then I did the following:

```
elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

But it shows the following error: `[2015-11-01 20:36:50,574][INFO ][bootstrap] es.config is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed.`

I tried several alternative ways of run it, like:

```
elasticsearch -f -D
```

But then I get the following error, and I can't find any useful for solve it, it seems to be related with file perms but not sure:

```
java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@33909752
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:210)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:127)
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:86)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:514)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getProvider(DateTimeZone.java:413)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(DateTimeZone.java:216)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault(DateTimeZone.java:151)
    at org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.java:79)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getChronology(DateTimeUtils.java:266)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.selectChronology(DateTimeFormatter.java:968)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:672)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:560)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeFormatter.java:644)
    at org.elasticsearch.Build.<clinit>(Build.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2015-11-01 20:40:57,602][INFO ][node                     ] [Centurius] version[2.0.0], pid[22063], build[de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z]
[2015-11-01 20:40:57,605][INFO ][node                     ] [Centurius] initializing ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load bundle [] due to jar hell
Likely root cause: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.0.0/libexec/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:210)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:173)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:340)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:113)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you took to install your ES? Since you're mentioning Homebrew, can you show the output you got during installation? What if you simply run `bin/elasticsearch` without any switches?

Comment: Hi it seems to be an issue of the last 2.0.0 version of elasticsearch https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14424#issuecomment-152902693 I downgraded to 1.4 version and everything is working fine now...

Comment: Gotcha, though 1.4 is old, you should use 1.7.3 instead if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some changes with `libexec` with Elasticsearch/homebrew installation and that is why it is failing to start. There is a PR [#45644](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/45644) currently being worked on. Till the PR gets accepted, you can use the same formula to fix the installation of Elasticsearch.

First uninstall the earlier/older version. Then edit the formula of Elasticsearch:

```
$ brew edit elasticsearch
```

And use the [formula](https://github.com/jasontedor/homebrew/blob/elasticsearch-2.0.0-and-head/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb) from the PR.

Then do `brew install elasticsearch`, it should work fine.

To start Elasticsearch, just do:

```
$ elasticsearch
```

`config` option is no longer valid. For custom config, use `path.config`:

```
$ elasticsearch --path.conf=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config
```