# Elasticsearch Runtime Exception curl_multi_exec() function is required for the client

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

My queue worker keeps throwing the error below:

```
[Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\RuntimeException]      
curl_multi_exec() function is required for the client.
```

The stack trace in the laravel log is:

```
[2015-11-02 01:52:35] local.ERROR: exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\RuntimeException' with message 'curl_multi_exec() function is required for the client.' in /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/app/Services/ElasticSearchClient.php(35): Elasticsearch\Client->__construct(Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/app/Providers/ElasticSearchServiceProvider.php(29): App\Services\ElasticSearchClient->__construct()
#2 [internal function]: App\Providers\ElasticSearchServiceProvider->boot()
#3 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(717): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\Providers\ElasticSearchServiceProvider))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\ElasticSearchServiceProvider), 19)
#7 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(718): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#9 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(105): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main}
```

I have no clue how to fix it.

I am using bitnami lamp stack to run a laravel application.

I am also using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html

In php.ini file, do I need to add the following line?:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

or do I need to do something additional?

Comment: Try this `echo function_exists('curl_multi_select');` If it doesn't print `"1"`, you don't have this function enabled. Then the solution will be: upgrade PHP or/and check `php.ini` (disabled functions). And yes, you should have `curl` lib installed and enabled.

Comment: Very similar question asked just before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469459/homebrew-cant-start-elastic-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing php5-curl. But that somehow uninstalled php5-mysql. So reinstalled that and php5-mcrypt and I am good to go.